# Download YouTube with Ruby (sourcecode)

Tags: ruby

I wish to download a video from YouTube and then extract its audio. Can anyone point me to some Ruby code to download a video? Thanks!

Comment: Love the title...all I can think is "I am downloading ur youtubz!" LOL

Comment: Youtube always change their page source...

Answer (score 9):

```
gem install curltube
```

then run 
`curltube <youtube-url>`

https://github.com/maxogden/curltube

Comment: The gem doesn't work in for me. However, `viddl-rb` gem works just fine.

Comment: now, `viddle-rb` recommends `youtube-dl`. tried `youtube-dl` and worked well.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how you would extract audio, but Ruby has many good scraping/mining libraries. You can use these to automate a browser and get scrape the data you need (e.g. the video embed code).

I recommend using a combination of mechanize and hpricot but here's a fairly comprehensive list:

Hpricot
Mechanize
Scrapi
Scrubyt
Nokogiri

You might also try Rio for downloading files/videos:

Rio: http://rio.rubyforge.org/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why use Hpricot and Mechanize, when Mechanize is already using Nokogiri internally?

Answer (score 4):

There's a more recent video downloader project [here on github](http://github.com/rb2k/viddl-rb) that allows you to grab flash video from different sites.

Answer (score 4):

Check https://github.com/davidgaya/youtube_rb

Its tiny and uncomplete.

It can get your expiring and customized URI for a video stream.

```
@video = YoutubeVideo.new "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzG4K2m_j5U"
@video.stream_uri
```

Once you have the stream_uri, you can download it, and process it using ffmpeg or gstreamer.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `1: from /Users/alejandro.ventura/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/cgi/core.rb:384:in `parse' NoMethodError (undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass)` Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some ruby code to download a youtube video. Unfortunely the library is written in python.

```
system("youtube-dl", "-o", filename, youtube_url)
```

You can extract the audio with the following

```
system("mplayer", "-dumpaudio", "-dumpfile", audo_filename, filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to some Ruby source code that will download the FLV from youtube:

http://www.rorcraft.com/2008/08/29/download-youtube-videos-with-ruby/

I haven't tried it out myself, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Also you and use [quvi](https://rubygems.org/gems/quvi). It understands youtube and lots of other sites. Also it can handle playlists. I've posted code sample here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23127407/98509