# How to download youtube videos in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube

How to fetch youtube video with its name fro, youtube when you have url of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try [quvi](https://rubygems.org/gems/quvi) gem which can extract most metadata from many media sites. For example you can get URLs of streams and pass them to downloader of your choice:

```
require 'quvi'

q = Quvi::Handle.new
media = q.parse_media("https://soundcloud.com/tasod/taso-du-val-originally-superior-ep-1")
media[:streams].map{ |m| m[:url] }
# => ["http://media.soundcloud.com/stream/U203a5DmFj9U?stream_token=1Q17x"]
```

Comment: do you know a simple way to install `libquvi` in MacOS X?

Answer (score 1):

Try [youtube_it](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) gem

Answer (score -6):

you can use the standard `open` when including [openuri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
youtube_video  = open('http://www.yotube.com/whatever') {|f| f.read }
```

Comment: This does not work. It just fetches the whole html document not the video.